# Questions about Pipeline check out code from Git

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

My pipeline includes two steps: first is to check code from git and another is the do the build. 
See my pipeline as below:

```
stages {
    stage('Sync code from GitLab'){
        steps {
            echo "Step 1: Sync code"
            ws(dir: '/home/tOmMy/jks_node/workspace/test') {
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/release_br']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'xxx', url: 'yyy']]])
                sh '''
                    pwd
                    ls -lt
                '''
            }
        }
    }

    stage('Build'){
        steps {
            echo "Step 2: Build"
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

However, when the Jenkins checkout code from git, I saw many directories:

```
[tOmMy@ubuntu workspace]$ tree
.
|-- xx
|   `-- yy
|       |-- zz
|       |-- zz@2
|       |-- zz@2@tmp
|       `-- zz@tmp
|-- test
|-- test@2
|-- test@2@tmp
`-- test@tmp
```

Where xx, yy, zz is the folder and job name in my Jenkins' server. 
The questions are:
1. which folder does the Jenkins checkout the source code? I compare test, test@2, xx/yy/zz, xx/yy/zz2, all of them have the same files. Why does jenkins check out code to such many places?

2. How can I get the actual Jenkins' checkout found in stage('Build')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually a declarative pipeline(if you are reading it from a repository) already check out the code itself in the "Checkout SCM" inside the job/build workspace folder.
If you allocate in another workspace (command ws) and check the code again you have 2 versions.
You should only do the build the checkout is already done in normal pipelines (if you use the jenkinsfile from a repo)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt, from my understanding, the code in the test folder are actually what I really need to concern, right?